# Relative Layout - A Number of questions

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have the following layout.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:text="@string/item_text"
    android:textColor="#787878"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <TextView 
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/item_internet"
    android:text="@string/item_internet"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_text" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_internet"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_internet"
    android:id="@+id/internetImage"/>

<TextView 
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/item_overnightStay"
    android:text="@string/item_overnightStay"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_internet"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_overnightStay" 
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_overnightStay"
    android:id="@+id/overnightStayImage"/>

<TextView 
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/item_wasteDisposal"
    android:text="@string/item_wasteDisposal"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_overnightStay" />

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_wasteDisposal"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_wasteDisposal"
    android:id="@+id/wasteDisposalImage"/>

<TextView 
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/item_toilet"
    android:text="@string/item_toilet"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_wasteDisposal" />

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_toilet"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_toilet"
    android:id="@+id/toiletImage"/>

<TextView 
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/item_electricity"
    android:text="@string/item_electricity"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_toilet"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_electricity"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_electricity"
    android:id="@+id/electricityImage"/>

<TextView 
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/item_cran"
    android:text="@string/item_cran"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_electricity"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_cran"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_cran"
    android:id="@+id/cranImage"/>

<TextView 
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/item_slipway"
    android:text="@string/item_slipway"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_cran"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_slipway"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_slipway"
    android:id="@+id/slipwayImage"/>

<TextView 
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/item_camping"
    android:text="@string/item_camping"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_slipway"/>

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_camping"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_camping"
    android:id="@+id/campingImage"/>


<TextView 
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:id="@+id/item_freshWater" 
    android:text="@string/item_freshWater"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_camping"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_freshWater"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_freshWater"
    android:id="@+id/freshWaterImage"/>


<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_freshWater" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
```

I generate the details for the list view dynamically so it can be different sizes. At the moment more than half the screen is taken up by the textViews and imageViews. This leaves around a 3rd left for the listView so it doesn't look too nice. Is it possible to use scroll view as well so the height of the listview could be bigger. I guess a way to implement this would be with weight but I am having problems doing that. As always any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to enable scrolling in ListView by using

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

in ListView. Also you can create more space by removing the titlebar using

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

above the SetContentView() method

Comment: the listView does scroll. But its not a particularly nice user experience to scroll on a 3rd of the screen. This is on a 3.7inch screen as well. It would be awful on anything smaller.